# File name with spaces piped to two xargs commands

Tags: find, shell-script, pipe, awk, xargs

I have a directory and many more subdirectories like the following -

```
file with spaces.txt
filewithsuperlonglines.txt
ordinaryfile.txt
binaryfile.bin
```

The command -

> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep text | grep -v long |
>   cut -d: -f1

produces the correct list of files (i.e. text files that do not contain very long lines)

```
./file with spaces.txt
./ordinaryfile.txt
```

But when I add another xargs to the end of the command I get errors -

> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep text | grep -v long |
>   cut -d: -f1 | xargs -0 awk -f someprocessing.awk

```
gawk: someprocessing.awk:3: fatal: cannot open file `./file' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The content of someprocessing.awk is not relevant as I get the same error if I use the `cat` command instead.

How do I get the command after the last pipe to work with files with spaces in their names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find -print0` produces *output* with null characters as delimiters.  `xargs -0` requires *input* with null characters as delimiters.  Your first `xargs` command gets its null characters from `find`; the second one sees newline characters instead.

Try this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 file | \
    grep text | \
    grep -v long | \
    cut -d: -f1 | \
    tr '\n' '\0' | \
    xargs -0 awk -f someprocessing.awk
```

(This should work for the GNU Coreutils version of `tr`; I'm not certain about other `tr` implementations.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution accepted will screw up if the file name contains ':'. The following will only fail if the file names contain ': ' and avoids the \0 manipulation:

```
find . -type f | parallel file | grep text | grep -v long |\
parallel --colsep ': ' awk -f someprocessing.awk {1}
```

It uses GNU Parallel so you get the awk done in parallel for free.

Watch the intro videos to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ